# Prevent outline-offset to resize

Tags: html, css

I have a outline and outline-offset defined inside my img tag

```
img {
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -2em;
}
```

Whenever I resize the page the outline does not stay in the same position instead it response to the page and shrinks further. How do I prevent this without creating new tags if possible?

I would like my outline to be positioned absolute to the img tag.

Comment: Can you provide a usage example and elaborate on what you are expecting and exactly what is happening that contradicts that?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/soxg074s/.  Is it possible that a media query is changing the font size which would in turn affect the computed size of `em` values?

Comment: Em values are relative to the font-size so yes, you problem probably comes from there.